# Platform-dependent behavior of fread with large nitems parameter

Tags: c, portability, fread, stdio

I created the test program below in an attempt to debug an issue in a larger system. The program attempts to `fread` a large chunk of data from a small file, but I've found that the behavior of the program differs across platforms.

**Expected behavior**

The behavior that I expect, and that I see on some platforms (e.g., Mac OS X, CentOS 6.4), is for the program to read N bytes (the size of the file) and then terminate with the `EOF` condition:

```
Read 2 bytes.
OK. EOF
```

**Anomalous behavior**

On some platforms (e.g., CentOS 6.6), the program reports 0 bytes read and fails with an error:

```
Read 0 bytes.
NOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!! Error: Operation not permitted
```

On these platforms, I can get the code to work as expected by reducing the `chunk` size "enough", but I'm not sure how to determine an acceptable size programmatically...

**Questions**

- Am I using `fread` correctly?
- Is there a more portable approach I should be using?
- Any suggested workarounds?

**Code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* file = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
    size_t chunk = 0x7FFFFFFF;
    char* buf = malloc(chunk);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int count = fread(buf, 1, chunk, file);
    printf("Read %i bytes.\n", count);
    int eof = feof(file);
    if (eof) {
        printf("OK. EOF\n");
    }
    int err = ferror(file);
    if (err) {
        printf("NOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!! Error: %s\n", strerror(err));
        return 1;
    }
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

For my test, I created test.txt with `echo "a" >test.txt`.

Comment: That should be `strerror(errno)`, not err. And four exclamation marks is just plain silly.

Comment: @Jens `err` is the variable I'm storing the error code from `ferror` in -- `fread` doesn't set `errno`

Comment: does your CentOS have enough memory and swap space?

Comment: @Les I assume so... it didn't fail at the `malloc` step.

Comment: according to the man page for read(), the max number of characters is limited by the system defined value: 'SSIZE_MAX'  Have you checked that value and made sure the 1/2 gig bytes the code is being ask to read is below that size.

Comment: the code could use 'stat()' to get the actual file size and then not ask for more bytes than the actual file size.

Comment: to use the errno system variable, may need to include the errno.h header file

Comment: @AaronNovstrup `strerror()` must be given an errno value to be meaningful. The `ferror()` function doesn't return an error number, it returns zero or nonzero according to ISO C.

Comment: @user3629249 - I think you mean 2 gig

Comment: +1 @user3629249 - for SSIZE_MAX, I found a link http://www.go-all.pl/debora.html that shows running "getconf -a" on CentOS 6.6 yields a value of SSIZE_MAX as 32767

Comment: @user3629249 I suspect that my issue is related to the SSIZE_MAX, and that definitely gives me a programmatic way to choose the chunk size. Thanks!